# How to Save Session of dynamic Checkbox in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, checkbox, laravel-8, laravel-blade

Checkboxes are populated from a @foreach loop in form of blade file. There, I want to show old value when editing a form even after get validation errors.

I have tried the below code,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <form class="needs-validation"  method="POST" action="{{ route('application.examination.student.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="form-group form-row">
                <label class="text-primary col-md-3"><b class="text-danger">*</b> Select your exam units</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8 pl-3">
                        @foreach($package_courses as $package_course)
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox col-sm-10">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input @error('{{$package_course->code}}') is-invalid @enderror" id="{{$package_course->code}}" name="exam_units[]" value="{{$package_course->id}}" {{ old('exam_units') == '$package_course->id' ? 'checked' : '' }}  required>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{$package_course->code}}"><b>{{$package_course->code}} {{$package_course->title}}</b> </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-end mt-4">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-2">Apply</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

It does nothing at all.

[image]

I expect to keep checked values remain in fields even after getting an validation error.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="exam_units[]" value="{{$package_course->id}}" {{ old('exam_units') && in_array($package_course->id,old('exam_units'))? 'checked' : '' }}  required>
```

**in_array** function Checks if a $**package_course->id** exists in an **old('exam_units'**) array, if its exists checked will checked